# "Rotation" logic on numerical variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation

I am working on an experiment where there are 100 groups and 4 versions of a product. The product version allocated to the group should be in such a way that the Group1 receiving Product A should not get Product A tomorrow. i.e. for each group the product version must rotate through the list before coming back to the initial case.

On any given day all 4 product versions should allocated to the 100 groups but day over day the version should rotate.

So i created my own version of a formula that i came across:

```
((group_number)+ seed%(number of versions))%(number of versions)) + 1

seed = calendar week of the year + day of the week
```

So if there are 4 versions and 100 groups then the o/p of the above formula will always be one of  (1,2,3,4).

Are there alternative ways of doing the same mathematically. I want to find if there is a difference in run-time it would take for millions of groups and versions. In that case this computation might slow down my whole simulation.

Comment: The computational issue is almost trivial--the formula you give is already extremely simple and quick to execute--but underlying it is a serious statistical issue of the design of your experiment: if you rotate all groups through the products in the same repetitive cycle, you can introduce systematic errors into your experiment.

Comment: This is not a design of experiment per se. This rotation is more to study how the population would behave when each of these product versions are allocated to them. Keeping aside the computation, is there another way to do the same thing. Thanks.